# useradd account cant login through GUI

Tags: virtualbox, chmod, chown, useradd, usermod

I'm using KALI fresh install.

Linux kali 5.2.0-kali2-686-pae #1 SMP Debian 5.2.9-2kali1 (2019-08-22) i686 GNU/Linux

I created a user using

```
useradd akkilah
```

Then i added this user to sudo group

```
usermod -aG sudo akkilah
```

for this user its fine to login through tty or Terminal `su` but i cant log in through GUI , when i check the Auth.log I found what is below. I added below loges cause it maybe helpfull but i dont know what i can make from it

[image]

Moreover, through my research on the internet, I found that this is maybe related to permission of the /home/akkilah folder, so I try to give it full permission, it  showed  me that it went successful but no permission change see loges below

> root@kali:/home# ls -ltr
>
> total 4
>
> drwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf 4096 Nov 28 16:47 akkilah
>
> root@kali:/home# chmod -v 777 akkilah
>
> mode of 'akkilah' changed from 0770 (rwxrwx---) to 0777 (rwxrwxrwx)
>
> root@kali:/home# ls -ltr
>
> total 4
>
> drwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf 4096 Nov 28 16:47 akkilah

Moreover I tryied to change the owner of the home folder with chown command, and even it give me successful run, but the owner didnt actually change .. see below

> root@kali:/home# chown -v  akkilah akkilah
>
> changed ownership of 'akkilah' from root to akkilah
>
> root@kali:/home# ls -ltr
>
> total 4
>
> drwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf 4096 Nov 28 16:47 akkilah

Comment: Reminder that `chmod 777` is a bad idea in almost any case. But as this is Kali, this is probably the least of your worries.

Comment: @Panki I knew its a bad idea, but i just want to know if the permission  for /home/akkilah is really the one causing the issue or not ? 

and can you explain a bit ( or give me a hint )  about your last sentence (   But as this is Kali, this is probably the least of your worries )

thanks alot for reply

Comment: The directory should be owned by `akkilah`. Use `chown` to set this and try again.

Comment: @Panki i run the command , but it showed me it ran successful whoever the owner did not change.  see the question i just edit it

Comment: Are you still logged in from a different session? Are you running the chown commands from a terminal when you're logged in via GUI?

Comment: @eblock I never knew that its a thing , however i try the same command from tty5 and it give the same exact output = as from GUI result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay , I fixed finally thanks for all foxes who help me out .

its turn out I have two issue integrated in one.

- to fix the GUI issue , i had to make the user own his home directory .obviously!
- 2nd issue that I was unable to change the owner of the home directory (/home/akkilah)

its turn out that when i tried to make a share folder in VirtualBox, I choosed my home directory, which resulted the Virtual-box **mounting my the home directory to share folder**. which, caused me not to be  able to change the owner , so the Soulation solution was .

1. umount my home drive `umount /home/akkilah`
2. change the owner of the directory `chown akkilah /home/akkilah`

after that every thing work like a charm